# How to fix this php count same value mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, count, sum

I'm having a problem with creating php file for counting how many same value ('COUNTRY') from mysql database and display on html table. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

$username="localhost";
$password="";
$database="project1";

mysql_connect($username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query="SELECT count(*), value 
FROM voting 
GROUP BY value 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 0 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC";$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();

echo "<b>

<center>Database Output</center>
</b>
<br>
<br>";
$i=0;while ($i < $num) {$field1-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"COUNTRY");
$field2-name=mysql_result($result,$i,"COUNT(*)");
echo "<b>
$field1-name $field2-name2</b>
<br>";$i++;}?>
```

Comment: `mysql_select_db` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and you should use `MYSQLi` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have no connection with the database i think!

a database connection looks like this..

```
mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

but a better option is to use mysqli_query's

mysqli_query("host", "username", "password", "dbname");
```

Hope you have a better look on this now ;)

For the query u use...

dont use `count()` in the query.

just use `mysql_num_rows` later in the script.